# how to calculate mean of data frame inside in series object (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

I have a data frame with following structure:

```
df.columns
Index(['first_post_date', 'followers_count', 'friends_count',
       'last_post_date','min_retweet', 'retweet_count', 'screen_name',
       'tweet_count',  'tweet_with_max_retweet', 'tweets', 'uid'],
        dtype='object')
```

Inside the *tweets* series, each cell is another data frame containing all the *tweets* of an user.

```
df.tweets[0].columns
Index(['created_at', 'id', 'retweet_count', 'text'], dtype='object')
```

I want to perform calculation on the *tweets* of each user.

For example, how can I find the average number of retweets of each user and the tweet with maximum retweets?

Comment: Use [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2],
                   'tweets': [pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1], 'retweet_count': [5, 10]}),
                              pd.DataFrame({'id': [2, 3], 'retweet_count': [55, 100]}),
                              pd.DataFrame({'id': [4, 5], 'retweet_count': [5555, 1000]})]})


stats = df['tweets'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.retweet_count.max(),
                                                x.retweet_count.mean()],
                                               index=['max', 'mean']))
```

Result is a dataframe where columns are stats for each user:

```
      max    mean
0    10.0     7.5
1   100.0    77.5
2  5555.0  3277.5
```